# I can not send POSTs forms and receive answers using the cURL

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm trying to send a POST to a website using the cURL and I want to receive the request in string format

My code is :

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

 //$post = array('text' => 'I am driving an ice cream truck');
  $params = array('I am driving an ice cream truck');
  $postData = 'text';

   foreach($params as $k => $v) 
   { 
      $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
   }
   rtrim($postData, '&');


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://beta.visl.sdu.dk/visl/en/parsing/automatic/parse.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//curl_exec($ch);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

echo $data;
?>
```

When I run the code I do not get the response of the request, only the page without any POST.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can pass an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Comment: If you do `echo $postData;` you will see it's probably not in the format you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some extra information required by the site, such as paser and visualitzation, also you can send an array to the CURLOPT_`POSTFIELDS`

So, build the required params like this:

```
$params = array(
 'text' => 'I am driving an ice cream truck',
 'paraser' => 'dep-eb',
  'visual' => 'niceline'
);
```

Then send the data like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://beta.visl.sdu.dk/visl/en/parsing/automatic/parse.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Notice the `http_build_query()` function to build the string params.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I really did not realize there were more parameters. =D